# Formatting A Dynamically Bound Datagrid's TextColumn

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, wpfdatagrid, .net-4.5

How can I format the text displayed in a bound column in my datagrid to the output of a function?

Say I have a function like this in my code-behind:

```
Function Test(ByVal str As String) As String
    Return Left(str, 5)
End Function
```

And a datagrid like:

```
    <DataGrid Name="dg_Users" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="User ID" Binding="{Binding UserID}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Username" Binding="{Binding Username}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Which is bound to a StronglyTyped IList.  (which is simply a SqlCeDataReader object looped through to add to a strongly typed list):

```
Private Shared Function Map(Of T As New)(ByVal _Rdr As IDataReader) As IList(Of T)
    Try
        Dim _t As Type = GetType(T)
        Dim _en As New List(Of T)()
        Dim _ht As New Hashtable()
        Dim _props As PropertyInfo() = _t.GetProperties()
        Parallel.ForEach(_props, Sub(info)
                                     _ht(info.Name.ToUpper()) = info
                                 End Sub)
        While _Rdr.Read()
            Dim newObject As New T()
            For index As Integer = 0 To _Rdr.FieldCount - 1
                Dim info As PropertyInfo = DirectCast(_ht(_Rdr.GetName(index).ToUpper()), PropertyInfo)
                If (info IsNot Nothing) AndAlso info.CanWrite Then
                    info.SetValue(newObject, IsNull(Of Object)(_Rdr.GetValue(index), Nothing), Nothing)
                End If
            Next
            _en.Add(newObject)
        End While
        _Rdr.Close()
        Return _en
        _ht.Clear() : _en.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

How do I format the `Username` column utilizing the `Test` function above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a read-only property (with just the getter) on the type (User I'm guessing) and bind to that instead. Makes it a lot easier.

Comment: So a seperate readonly property and simply return my function in that...    i'll try

Comment: That is, return what you'd normally return from your function - i.e. Left(Username, 5); not sure about the exact VB syntax, it's been a while since I left VB :)

Comment: No dice... I guess I should state that the StronglyTyped IList is autmagically generated.  I'll post it above.

Comment: Ok what I meant is to add the property to the type of items in the list; it would be something like ShortUsername and you'd bind to that in the XAML instead of directly on the Username. Is that what you tried?